# I deleted lib32-ncurses, how do I fix it?

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I deleted the lib32-ncurses manually from the /usr/lib folder (I know...)

I was having issues with a compiled PHP and libncursesw.so.5

It broke Arch. So I boot from my a live cd but if I try to, mounted the partition but when trying to chroot to the root mount at /mnt I get:

```
/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses2.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: After booting from the livecd, trying copying its `/usr/lib/libncurses2.so.6` into the mounted `/usr/lib`, then seeing if that works. If it does, you probably want to reinstall the package just to be sure.

Comment: yeah, `bash` needs all that jazz. symlink some other shell over `/bin/sh` - like `ln -sf /usr/lib/initcpio/busybox /bin/sh` or something.

Comment: @mikeserv Did it, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: well, if you did it from outside the `chroot` then it probably wont be `/` at the head of the path. Anyway, you can just use the `pacman` `-r` argument to install the package you need from without the `chroot` as well. `pacman -r /path/to/chroot -S ncurses --force`

Comment: @TomHunt The issue is I have libncurses5 on the live CD

Comment: @mikeserv I try again the first workaround and it now displays "bash: applet not found"

Comment: I managed to downgrade the kernel without using chroot. Just doing pacman -U /path/to/kernel but now Arch stalls on boot. Specifically on "Started Accounts Service"

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to boot from an Arch ISO somehow.  After that, you can probably upgrade the kernel by following [Option 2: Reinstall Kernel](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_Panics) from the Arch Linux Wiki article, "Kernel Panics". That article includes doing a `chroot` to the hard disk mounted by the ISO, so you can use `pacman` on the latest kernel you've got in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/`. Look in that same directory for a version 5 ncurses package, and update it, too, while you're at it.

Comment: Sure, I'm following that guide. But I get the same error message after typing "arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash" but with a different libncurses.